# How to insert data in database after payment successful through instamojo

Tags: instamojo

I have integrated instamojo payment api with my website on PHP.
I can also insert data into my database before payment api is called.
Now how can i insert data into my database after my payment is successful !

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? It is related to *what* to insert or *how* to insert.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary there are few fields which are taken by api but i want few more field values to come to the file in the redirect url how can i do it ?

Comment: U should use Webhook-URL for achieve this. For more detail refer [This Support Document](https://support.instamojo.com/hc/en-us/articles/208485755-Webhook-URL) and inside it u add ur custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save this code as php file in your host and then set this file URL as web hook URL for Product/Payment link in Instamojo. You can also check whether this works on Web hook checking page in Instamojo.

```
<?php
/*
Basic PHP script to handle Instamojo RAP webhook.
*/

$data = $_POST;
$mac_provided = $data['mac'];  // Get the MAC from the POST data
unset($data['mac']);  // Remove the MAC key from the data.
$ver = explode('.', phpversion());
$major = (int) $ver[0];
$minor = (int) $ver[1];
if($major >= 5 and $minor >= 4){
     ksort($data, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
}
else{
     uksort($data, 'strcasecmp');
}
// You can get the 'salt' from Instamojo's developers page(make sure to log in first): https://www.instamojo.com/developers
// Pass the 'salt' without <>
$mac_calculated = hash_hmac("sha1", implode("|", $data), "<YOUR_SALT>");
if($mac_provided == $mac_calculated){
    if($data['status'] == "Credit"){
        // Payment was successful, mark it as successful in your database.
        // You can acess payment_request_id, purpose etc here. 
    }
    else{
        // Payment was unsuccessful, mark it as failed in your database.
        // You can acess payment_request_id, purpose etc here.
    }
}
else{
    echo "MAC mismatch";
}
?>
```